# Is it possible to make Doxygen to expand enum initializers?

Tags: c, doxygen

For the following input:

```
enum A  
{  
  A1 = 1,
  A2 = 2  
};  
enum B  
{  
  B1 = A2,  
  B2 = A2 * A2 + 1  
}
```

I would like doxygen to expand/resolve initializers of B::B1 and B::B2. I would like to have respectably `2` and `5` in initializers of B1 and B2, rather then `A2` and `A2 * A2 + 1`. Is it possible? If so, how can this be achieved?
Please mind that I am asking only about enum initializers. Those are known at the compile time, so (in theory) doxygen should be able to compute.

EDIT: Removed `;` from enum definitions.

Comment: With the `;` inside the `enum` declaration your code wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible, **but**, for a simple case as you presented, you can *fake* it by using `#define` in a way that would work for your code, and still be possible for `doxygen` to resolve the values.

Your code can look like this:

```
#define A_1 1
#define A_2 2
#define B_1 A_2
#define B_2 (A_2 * A_2 + 1)

enum A  
{  
  A1 = A_1,
  A2 = A_2
};

enum B  
{  
  B1 = B_1,
  B2 = B_2
};
```

And in the doxygen configuration you need to enable `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` and `MACRO_EXPANSION`.

Comment: I tested it and it works. It's a pity there is no better support for enums built-in in Doxygen, your solution works for this simple problem but does not allow to use the enum value in some other part of the Doxygen documentation for example. (By the way names starting with underscores are reserved for the compiler/standard-library implementation in C and C++).

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked. I edited the question to avoid starting the names with underscore, thanks for the tip. It was just an attempt to differentiate their nature more, but you are right.

Comment: It is not my question, I can not accept it, I only placed a bounty on it ;-)

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that bit :) sorry then